# Cortana, Xamarin and Microsoft Band Integration

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, microsoft-band

I'm looking to develop a multi-platform app using Xamarin, that accesses the voice of a user through the band, processing this as text to be parsed through Cortana. The key is to have it multi-platform so my main question is, can IOS and android connect to the Microsoft bands microphone, doing this?

Here is some links that might be helpful including the Microsoft Band SDK for Xamarin, however I couldn't find anything that would be able to access the microphone of the band.

[Xamarin Microsoft Band SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/view/microsoft-band-sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Band SDK does not expose the microphone to third-party applications (on any platform).  The Cortana integration with the Band is available only on Windows.